# running antlr inside a javafx and swing app

Tags: swing, javafx, antlr4

I have built a gui with javafx and swing and when I add an action listener to parse the expression in a textfield I get a error, I am not sure what the problem is.

the error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at functionparsergui.Test.parseFunction(Test.java:110)
at functionparsergui.Test.access$000(Test.java:38)
at functionparsergui.Test$2.actionPerformed(Test.java:88)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 2).
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSimulator.deserialize(ATNSimulator.java:114)
at edu.chrr.util.function.FunctionLexer.<clinit>(FunctionLexer.java:504)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 2).
... 41 more
```

My code starting from declaring the actionlistener is as follows:

```
    ActionListener clearField = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            exprField.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Input Cleared");
        }
    };

    clearButton.addActionListener(clearField);


    ActionListener parserButton;
    parserButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String expression = exprField.getText();
            String nowhiteExpr = expression.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            parseFunction(nowhiteExpr, frame);


        }
    };

    parseButton.addActionListener(parserButton);


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        }
    });
}

private static void parseFunction(final String function, final JFrame frame) {

    try {
                ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(function);
                FunctionLexer lexer = new FunctionLexer(input);
                CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream((TokenSource) lexer);
                FunctionParser parser = new FunctionParser(tokens);
                parser.start();
                int errorsCount = parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors();
                if (errorsCount == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Syntax is Correct");

                } else {

                    Token t = parser.getCurrentToken();
                    String msg = "Syntax Incorrect: Missing " + t.getText();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, msg);

                }

            } catch (RecognitionException ex) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Syntax is Incorrect");
            }
}





private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
    // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
    Scene scene = createScene();
    fxPanel.setScene(scene);
}

private static Scene createScene() {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
           return (scene);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 4.1 is not compatible with ANTLR 4.0. You are generating your code with ANTLR 4.1 but attempting to run it with the ANTLR 4.0 runtime library.